# I would like ArrayCollection instead of Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I've wrote in a twig view this:

```
{% for catalog in box.getCatalogs() %}

{% for mod in catalog.getModel() %}

{{ dump(catalog.getModel()) }}

{% endfor %}

 {% else %}
  nothing
 {% endfor %}
```

I get this in a dump
[image]

So how do get an array of collection in a twig view,?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to worry about the type of Collection object, Both `ArrayCollection` and `PersistentCollection` implement the `Collection` interface and work the same way. The difference is that PersistentCollection contains objects that have been persisted in the DB and *might* hit the database when you iterate over them.

If you use type-hinting, just hint at `Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection`.

If you write

```
{% for mod in catalog.getModel() %}
    {{ dump(mod) }}
{% endfor %}
```

in your twig template, you should see your objects.

Comment: Hi @janh, First looping is to display all catalogs, and the second loop is to display model per catalog. The second loop don't give me an array of object.

Comment: @MethodProg can you add the output of `{{ dump(mod) }}` to your question?

Comment: Yes here is the dump {{ dump(mod) }} link https://i.stack.imgur.com/wF6Jx.png

Comment: @MethodProg Those are what you got from `{{ dump(catalog.getModel()) }}`, where you dumped the Collection. You should look at `mod`, which is one element of the Collection in your for loop.

Comment: Hi @janh, this is the result of he dump https://imgur.com/dB8sNNC and it work now...Could not display my picture but this is another question with VichUploader and symfony asset all thanks !!!